# Assigning database name to a variable in SSDT database publish script (automatically generated)

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools

All I would like to do is assign the name `TestDatabase` to the variable 
`@test`.

For some reason I can't seem to make it work. 
What is it that I could be missing here?

Here is my sample taken from the automatically generated script using visual studio.

```
 GO
 :setvar testdb "TestDatabase"

 --TSQL bit
 DECLARE @test nvarchar(10)
 set @test=$(testdb)  -- tried with $testdb, $[testdb]
```

Invalid column name 'testdb'.
** An error was encountered during execution of batch. Exiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 GO
 :setvar testdb "TestDatabase"

 --TSQL bit
 DECLARE @test nvarchar(10)
 set @test='$(testdb)'
```

Comment: how come i forgot trying that bit?. Thank you very much @sidux. That was super quick.